# Spring security: custom login form with locale

Tags: security, spring, locale

I need to develop custom login form which allows user to select language (locale).
When user select locale from  page has to reload and display in new locale.
After page is submited (login button is pressed) then the selected locale has to be set to spring app.

I spent a lot of hours to googling some solution. unfortunatelly there is no working solution :-(((

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could register a LocaleChangeInterceptor which allows the change of the users locale. Checkout the docs at http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/mvc.html#mvc-localeresolver

Comment: Did you tried it? Can you show working example? It works with spring. But doesn't work with login page of spring security.

Comment: Just setup your own login form using the setup described here http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/appendix-namespace.html#nsa-form-login and add the locale select. On submit you post the form using the variables of http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.html to /j_spring_security_check using

Comment: Yes. You are right. Problem was vaadin integration. Thank you.

Comment: The link is broken: 404 - Page not found